# TableView - RowFactory does not apply CSS style

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I have a tableview showing "incomes" and "expenses". I want to set the background-color of the rows that are incomes (means, the value of an entity >= 0) to a different color than expenses.
I add styleclasses to the specific rows, but they don't seem to apply the styles.
It works, if I apply the style directly like this: `setStyle("...");` in the row factory.

Here is what I have:

FXML:

```xml
<!-- ....... -->
                <TableView fx:id="expensesTableView" editable="true" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn text="Title" prefWidth="${expensesTableView.width*0.35}">
                            <cellValueFactory>
                                <PropertyValueFactory property="title" />
                            </cellValueFactory>
                        </TableColumn>
                        <TableColumn text="Category" prefWidth="${expensesTableView.width*0.25}">
                            <cellValueFactory>
                                <PropertyValueFactory property="category" />
                            </cellValueFactory>
                        </TableColumn>
                        <TableColumn text="Period" prefWidth="${expensesTableView.width*0.25}">
                            <cellValueFactory>
                                <PropertyValueFactory property="period" />
                            </cellValueFactory>
                        </TableColumn>
                        <TableColumn text="Value" prefWidth="${expensesTableView.width*0.15}">
                            <cellValueFactory>
                                <PropertyValueFactory property="value" />
                            </cellValueFactory>
                            <!--<cellFactory>
                                <HighlightIncomeCellFactory />
                            </cellFactory>-->
                        </TableColumn>
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
<!-- ....... -->
```

CSS:

```css
.positive-value {
    rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Java-Class:

```
    //......
            expensesTableView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Transaction>, TableRow<Transaction>>() {
                @Override
                public TableRow<Transaction> call(TableView<Transaction> tableView) {
                    return new TableRow<Transaction>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(Transaction person, boolean empty){
                            super.updateItem(person, empty);
                            if (person == null || !person.getValue().contains("-")) {
                                getStyleClass().remove("income-row");
                                //setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;"); //This would actually work...
                            } else {
                                getStyleClass().add("income-row");
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
    //......
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Here's a link to the stylesheet I apply to the scene: https://github.com/TrudleR/ExpensesCalculator/blob/master/src/main/resources/stylesheet.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css style is wrong. It should be something like this:

```css
.income-row {
    -fx-background: white;
}
```

Note that you also should take care of styling selected rows. Otherwise you cannot distinguish selected rows with positive income from unselected rows with positive income based on the background color, e.g.

```css
.table-view:row-selection .income-row:selected {
    -fx-background: gray;
}
```

Furthermore you probably don't want empty rows to be styled as income rows. Furthermore you need to make sure not to add the style class multiple times. You could use

```
if (person == null || person.getValue().contains("-")) {
    getStyleClass().remove("income-row");
} else if (!getStyleClass().contains("income-row")) {
    getStyleClass().add("income-row");
}
```

instead.

#### Edit

In your stylesheet you have additional rules for styling rows:

```css
.table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: rgb(153, 102, 51);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
}

.table-row-cell:odd{
    -fx-background-color: rgb(165, 114, 63);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    /*-fx-padding: 0.0em; /* 0 */
}

.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #005797;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 1;
}
```

Since a property in a rule is only used if it's the last rule with the top precedence, the above style is overwritten by rules like e.g. `.table-row-cell:odd`.

You could make take precedence by specifying the `income-row` class selector in addition to the other selectors, e.g.

```css
.table-row-cell.income-row,
.table-row-cell.income-row:odd{
    -fx-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.table-row-cell.income-row:selected {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

Setting the style using `setStyle` works, since inline styles always take precedence over stylesheet rules.

Comment: Also note the logic in `updateItem(...)` is not sufficient. If the cell is reused such that the item changes from one non-null `Person` not containing `"-"` to another non-null `Person` not containing `"-"`, the `styleClass` list will end up with multiple `"income-row"` entries. This means that the code is prone to memory leaks (indefinitely growing list) and that the call to `remove("income-row")` will not have the desired effect (only removing one of potentially many copies).

Comment: The CSS-semantics works on other parts of the application. I tried using "white" instead, but it didn't change anything. The other tipps are good, but they will only get important if I get the styling to work.

Comment: I updated the question: If I call "setStyle", it actually works. But that's not an acceptable solution, more a bad workaround if you ask me. :) Thx for your effort by the way.

Comment: @TrudleR: I've just tested the fixed version (See James_D's comment) and it works. The only thing that could go wrong here are other rules taking precedence. Are there other rules in the stylesheet or do you use other stylesheets?

Comment: @fabian: https://github.com/TrudleR/ExpensesCalculator/blob/master/src/main/resources/stylesheet.css This is my stylesheet. There are other rules, yeah, but I think they should be overriden, shouldn't they?

Comment: @TrudleR: There are rules there applicable to table rows and since they also have a single class selector, they should overwrite the values, since they come later in the stylesheet and even are more concrete in some cases...

Comment: @fabian: Ah, so the hierarchical order still has more priority? That's interesting! Need to try it out when I'm back on PC.

Comment: @TrudleR: It's complicated, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity (IDK if `!important` works in JavaFX) and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/StyleableProperty.html

Comment: I put the "income-row" section in CSS at the end and it worked! You are right though, I need to override other sections too. That's very interesting, I didn't thought that javafx would pay attention to the order of selectors. BTW: I've seen the `!important` keyword in other project, so I'm kinda sure this works too. But I rather go with the order-hierarchy than using keywords to workaround the non-default functionality.
PS: I just see that you edited your answer. Gonna report back! :) Edit: Like a charm! The real problem was the order. Thank you Fabian!!